# Callbacks on echarts bar graph (e.g. onClick)

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, echarts

I'm trying to use echarts in one of my project and haven't worked with echarts before. I've found quit good examples to start with but I want to achieve some additional functionality on bar charts like some callbacks on clicking on individual bars. I'm able to see formatter function for tool-tip [here](https://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/tooltip.html#infographic-en) but couldn't find click event. Also, is there any event for clicking on labels on x-axis ?
I've checked documentation for echarts [here](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#graphic.elements-rect.onclick) and found callback events but couldn't find a way to get them working for bar charts. Any help/suggestion or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

myChart.on("click", function (event) {    
    console.log(event);
});
```

the 'click' event gets fired only when clicking the bars.

Comment: This works on getting to console log the item, however, when I am trying to run any other methods outside of this function, it's not reading it correctly... I am using Vue and have a method that needs the event info... but the method can not be reached... any ideas as to why????